# Python Pandas: how do I fill none empty rows with its corresponding column names?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the original df:

```
A   B   C 
32      4
    2   
2       
9       2
2   6
```

I want to fill in cells that have data with the column names.The output will look like this:

```
A   B   C 
A       C 
    B   
A       
A       C 
A   B
```

Thanks
RJ

Answer (score 3):

Another way is `np.where` and would be very fast as well:

```
out = df.copy()
out[:] = np.where(df.notna(),df.columns,np.nan)
```

---

```
print(out)

     A    B    C
0    A  NaN    C
1  NaN    B  NaN
2    A  NaN  NaN
3    A  NaN    C
4    A    B  NaN
```

Comment: Using np.where here is nearly `1.4~2` times faster than the rest of solutions, checked on the sample of df with 1000 entries. Already upvoted ;).

Answer (score 2):

We could do `stack` and `unstack`

```
s=df.stack()
s[:]=s.index.get_level_values(1)
s=s.unstack()
s
Out[496]: 
     A    B    C
0    A  NaN    C
1  NaN    B  NaN
2    A  NaN  NaN
3    A  NaN    C
4    A    B  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we can use `.transform` & `.mask`:

```
m = df.notna()
df = m.transform(lambda s: [s.name] * s.size).mask(~m)
```

---

```
#print(df)
     A    B    C
0    A  NaN    C
1  NaN    B  NaN
2    A  NaN  NaN
3    A  NaN    C
4    A    B  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
df.where(df.isnull(),df.columns.tolist())

[out]
A   B   C
A   NaN C
NaN B   NaN
A   NaN NaN
A   NaN C
A   B   NaN
```